# show function possibilities after "os." in python's IDLE

Tags: python, function, python-idle

I want IDLE to display to me all the possible functions after I enter a '.' for any library. How can this be done? or can it be done?

Comment: It works fine for me. There are a lot of attributes in the `os` module so it takes a couple seconds for the list to pop up, but pop up it does.

Answer (score 2):

In IDLE, this is the closest you're going to get:

```
>>> import os
>>> dir(os)
['F_OK', 'MutableMapping', 'O_APPEND', 'O_BINARY', 'O_CREAT', 'O_EXCL', 'O_NOINHERIT', 'O_RANDOM', 'O_RDONLY', 'O_RDWR', 'O_SEQUENTIAL', 'O_SHORT_LIVED', 'O_TEMPORARY', 'O_TEXT', 'O_TRUNC', 'O_WRONLY', 'P_DETACH', 'P_NOWAIT', 'P_NOWAITO', 'P_OVERLAY', 'P_WAIT', 'R_OK', 'SEEK_CUR', 'SEEK_END', 'SEEK_SET', 'TMP_MAX', 'W_OK', 'X_OK', '_Environ', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_copyreg', '_execvpe', '_exists', '_exit', '_get_exports_list', '_get_masked_mode', '_make_stat_result', '_make_statvfs_result', '_pickle_stat_result', '_pickle_statvfs_result', '_putenv', '_unsetenv', '_wrap_close', 'abort', 'access', 'altsep', 'chdir', 'chmod', 'close', 'closerange', 'curdir', 'defpath', 'device_encoding', 'devnull', 'dup', 'dup2', 'environ', 'errno', 'error', 'execl', 'execle', 'execlp', 'execlpe', 'execv', 'execve', 'execvp', 'execvpe', 'extsep', 'fdopen', 'fsdecode', 'fsencode', 'fstat', 'fsync', 'get_exec_path', 'getcwd', 'getcwdb', 'getenv', 'getlogin', 'getpid', 'getppid', 'isatty', 'kill', 'linesep', 'link', 'listdir', 'lseek', 'lstat', 'makedirs', 'mkdir', 'name', 'open', 'pardir', 'path', 'pathsep', 'pipe', 'popen', 'putenv', 'read', 'readlink', 'remove', 'removedirs', 'rename', 'renames', 'rmdir', 'sep', 'spawnl', 'spawnle', 'spawnv', 'spawnve', 'startfile', 'stat', 'stat_float_times', 'stat_result', 'statvfs_result', 'strerror', 'supports_bytes_environ', 'symlink', 'sys', 'system', 'times', 'umask', 'unlink', 'urandom', 'utime', 'waitpid', 'walk', 'write']
```

Comment: oh dang, i was hoping to have them pop up while i was typing the '.' like java in netbeans ha

Comment: you could use Aptana(or eclipse) or some other ide that provides this functionality... I like aptana its real nice for py devel at least imho

Comment: Well, you're in luck.  Python is open source, so you could put a feature request on the Python tracker along with a patch implementing the feature and have it ignored for the next five years, then closed because it's out of date.

Comment: PyCharm is my favorite Python IDE. Has excellent intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

like so:

```
import os
dir(os)
```

you might also consider writing a small function that will format the output of dir in a more readable way

Answer (score 1):

Return the names of **functions** in a module:

```
def methods(module):
    return [module.__dict__.get(attr).__name__ for attr in dir(module) if isinstance(module.__dict__.get(attr), types.FunctionType)]
```

example:

```
import re
methods(re) // ['_compile', '_compile_repl', '_expand', '_pickle', '_subx', 'compile', 'escape', 'findall', 'finditer', 'match', 'purge', 'search', 'split', 'sub', 'subn', 'template']
```

Comment: Nice answer! Doesn't give you all that other junk in there.